# C unsigned long long miscalculation

Tags: c

I don't even know how to name this problem, so first I will present some code:

```
void hsvm2dcd72f(const hsvm_t *src, dcd72f_t *result, unsigned long long range)
{
    int h, s, v;
    int kh, ks, kv;
    int i;
    int indexes[72];
    int values[72];
    unsigned long long sum = 0;
    unsigned long long temp = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < 72; i++)
    {
        result->values[i] = 0;
        values[i] = 0;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < src->length; i++)
    {

        h = (int) src->content[i].h;
        s = (int) src->content[i].s;
        v = (int) src->content[i].v;

        // kwantyzacja H
        if ((h >= 316) || (h < 20))
            kh = 0;
        else if ((h >= 20) && (h < 40))
            kh = 1;
        else if ((h >= 40) && (h < 75))
            kh = 2;
        else if ((h >= 75) && (h < 155))
            kh = 3;
        else if ((h >= 155) && (h < 190))
            kh = 4;
        else if ((h >= 190) && (h < 270))
            kh = 5;
        else if ((h >= 270) && (h < 295))
            kh = 6;
        else if ((h >= 295) && (h < 316))
            kh = 7;

        // kwantyzacja S
        if ((s >= 0) && (s <= 20))
            ks = 0;
        if ((s > 20) && (s <= 70))
            ks = 1;
        if ((s > 70) && (s <= 100))
            ks = 2;

        //kwantyzacja V
        if ((v >= 0) && (v <= 20))
            kv = 0;
        if ((v > 20) && (v <= 70))
            kv = 1;
        if ((v > 70) && (v <= 100))
            kv = 2;

        values[9 * kh + 3 * ks + kv]++;
    }

    quicksorti((int*) &indexes, (int*) &values, 72);

    //norm
    for (i = 72 - 8; i < 72; i++)
        sum += (unsigned long long) values[indexes[i]];

    unsigned long long temp1 = 65535;
    temp = (unsigned long long) range;
    if(temp == temp1)
        printf("ok");
    for (i = 72 - 8; i < 72; i++)
    {
        result->values[indexes[i]] = values[indexes[i]]*temp1 / sum;
    }
}

struct dcd72f // result struct
{
    unsigned long long values[72]; /**< dcd descriptor values. */
};
typedef struct dcd72f dcd72f_t;
```

It shows "ok" after the comparison so temp1 and temp are equal (that's something I was aiming for), but according to variable I am getting different results in `result->values[indexes[i]]`, with `temp` and `temp1`. The `temp1` results are correct ones but I need `temp` to be flexible.

I am using GCC with eclipse on Windows.  Any idea how to solve this?

Edit:
`printf("%llu\n", temp);` and `printf("%llu\n", temp1);` both return 65535...

Comment: How is `result` allocated? Any chance you're clobbering some memory and overwriting `temp`?

Comment: @mlodziaszka what is `range`?

Comment: struct dcd72f <--this struct is result
{
 unsigned long long values[72]; /**< dcd descriptor values. */
};

Comment: You don't show `values[]` the array being initialized; you don't show `indexes` being initialized. You don't show the definition of the structure type that is the type of `result`.  You don't show how `sum` is calculated. You don't show how `range` is calculated. That's a lot of missing information. (_When you do add the information, edit the question rather than adding a comment, please!_)

Comment: @FatalError to be honest I don't think that `temp` is overwrited cos it's the same as `temp1` 1 line above using it and as I said both return the same number.

Comment: This: `(int*) &indexes` smells like anything-but-promising.

Answer (score -1):

You have never compare two floats in a condition. Real numbers in a range are infinite, but a float-double are not. It has infinite blanks and they give you an approximation to the value. The comparator == is to binary level. This must be your problem.